# Using the DAOPattern with authentication

Tags: morphia

I'm having some trouble to authenticate now. Try to add the following code to the constructors of my own DAO-classes:

```
public MyDAO(Morphia morphia, Mongo mongo, String dbName){
   super(mongo, morphia, dbName);
             // Line below added
   mongo.getDB(dbName).authenticate("username", "password".toCharArray());

             // Then I tried this
   if (mongo.getDB(dbName).isAuthenticated()){
      System.out.println("SUCCESS!!!");
   }else{
      System.out.println("FAILURE");
   }
}
```

**Nothing works.** I change /etc/mongod.conf file, add auth=true.

```
FAILURE
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "err" : "not authorized for upsert on pndTestTemp.myEntity" , "code" : 16538 , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 46 , "ok" : 1.0}
```